# How to add string beside iterated value of for loop which are divisible by 3,5 & both?

Tags: javascript

I want to run a loop from 1 to 10 & ​want to print **"divisible by 3"** beside all the numbers which are divisible by 3 same for 5, print **"divisible by both"** beside the numbers which are divisible by 3 & 5 both as explained below.

Expected Output:-

```
  1
  2
  3 'divisible by 3'
  4
  5 'divisible by 5'
  6 'divisible by 3'
  7
  8
  9 'divisible by 3'
 10 'divisible by 5'
 11
 12 'divisible by 3'
 13
 14
 15 'divisible by both'
```

Comment: Where's your current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty straight forward by using the arithmetic operator `%`,

```js
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];


arr.forEach(x=>{

    if(x%3==0 && x%5==0){
    console.log(`${x} is divisible by both`);
  }else if(x%3 == 0){
        console.log(`${x} is divisible by 3`);
  }else if(x%5 == 0){
    console.log(`${x} is divisible by 5`);
  }else{
    console.log(`${x}`);
  }
})
```

,

Comment: @GoldenretriverYT: That, and the answer is bad too. For an incredibly simple FizzBuzz problem, it uses an array for no reason and the formatting is all over the place.